# How to eliminate repeated field with GROUP BY clause?

Tags: postgresql

I have 3 tables called:

```
1.app_tenant pk:id, fk:pasar_id
 ---+--------+-----------+
 id | nama   | pasar_id  |
----+--------+-----------+
  1 | joe    |         1 | 
  2 | adi    |         2 | 
  3 | adam   |         3 |

2.app_pasar pk:id
----+------------- +
 id | nama         |
----+------------- +
  1 | kosambi      | 
  2 | gede bage    |  
  3 | pasar minggu |   


 3.app_kios pk:id, fk:tenant_id
----+---------------+----------
 id | nama          |tenant_id
----+-------------- +----------
 1  | kios1         |1
 2  | kios2         |2
 3  | kios3         |3
 4  | kios4         |1
 5  | kios5         |1
 6  | kios6         |2
 7  | kios7         |2
 8  | kios8         |3
 9  | kios9         |3
```

Then with a `LEFT JOIN` query and grouping by `id` in every table I want to displaying data like this:

```
----+---------------+------------+-----------
 id | nama_tenant   |nama_pasar  |nama_kios
----+-------------- +------------------------
  1 | joe           |kosambi     |kios 1
  2 | adi           |gede bage   |kios 2
  2 | adam          |pasar minggu|kios 3
```

but after I execute this query, data are not shown as expected. The problem is
redundancy in the `nama_tenant` field. How can I eliminate repeated `nama_tenant`records?

This is my query:

```
select a.id,a.nama as nama_tenant,
       b.nama as nama_pasar,
       c.nama as nama_kios
from app_tenant a 
left join app_pasar b on a.id=b.id
left join app_kios c on a.id= c.tenant_id
group by 
      a.id,
      b.id,
      c.id
```

Table definitions:

```
CREATE TABLE app_tenant (
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  nama character varying,
  pasar_id integer);

CREATE TABLE app_kios (
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  nama character varying,
  tenant_id integer REFERENCES app_tenant);
```

Comment: app_pasar table definition is missing and since the `id`s are all primary keys it makes no sense to `GROUP BY` on them: they are by definition unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that tenants can have multiple kiosks. From your sample data it looks like you want to display the first kiosk of every tenant (although "first" is a vague concept on strings, here I use alphabetical sort order). Your query would be like this:

```
SELECT t.id, t.nama AS nama_tenant, p.nama AS nama_pasar, k.nama AS nama_kios
FROM app_tenant t
LEFT JOIN app_pasar p ON p.id = t.pasar_id
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT tenant_id, nama, rank() OVER (PARTITION BY tenant_id ORDER BY nama) AS rnk
  FROM app_kios
  WHERE rnk = 1) k ON k.tenant_id = t.id
ORDER BY t.id
```

The sub-query on `app_kios` uses a [window function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/tutorial-window.html) to get the first kiosk name after sorting the names of the kiosk for each tenant.

I would also suggest to use meaningful aliases for table names instead of simply a, b, c.

Comment: patrick your mean the problem is 'one to many' relation between app_tenant  and app_kios, am I need to restructure/alter my table structure?

Comment: actualy I think to adding kios_id field in app_tenant teble, but I get problem in user interface when I create entry to form tenant. because form tenant forbiden to load kios_id.

Comment: It appears you should change your UI design. If a single tenant can have multiple kiosks, then your form should that same master-client (one-to-many) design.

Comment: do you agree with me to adding new column 'kios_id' in table tenant, to join between them?

Comment: No, because then you'd have to duplicate tenant names for those that have multiple kiosks. You should look at your UI design, your table design is ok